# Jquery targeting children of fieldset

Tags: jquery, scope, toggle

I am trying to create collapsable fieldsets,  the idea is you click a legend and the child fields are shown.

The problem is that the scope does not seem to work, so

```
$('.field', $(this).parent() ).show();
```

If I click a legend I expected the fields with a wrapper of (.field) within the context ( $(this).parent() ) to be shown, however all the .fields are effected

what am I doing wrong?

**ANSWER**

```
$('.field', $(this).closest('fieldset') ).show();
```

edit there are multiple fieldset/legends

**some of the html**
http://pastie.org/8953182

Comment: The parent is probably not the right element, post the HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're wanting the siblings of the clicked item to show?

```
$(this).parent().find('.field').show();
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Difficult to determine exactly what they're after without the corresponding HTML :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
//instead of this: $('.field', $(this).parent() ).show();// here $(this).parent() would be undefined.
```

your code runs with reference error: http://jsfiddle.net/C3988/

---

```
$('.field').filter(function(){
   return $(this).parent();
).show();
```

Or simply like this:

```
$('.field').parent().show();
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3988/1/)